# Sort sentences based on formatting

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, sorting, regex

I have a list of sentences in Google Sheets, each word in a different column.

1. There is a **stupid** man.
2. How we came here we don't **know anything about**.
3. Finally, **it has** come to this.
4. Shaking my **head**.

How can I sort these sentences in alphabetical order by the **first word in bold**?

This is the result I'm looking for:

1. Shaking my **head**.
2. Finally, **it has** come to this.
3. How we came here we don't **know anything about**.
4. There is a **stupid** man.

Better still if I can do this in Google Docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT({A:A, IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A, 
 "head|it has|know anything about|stupid"))}, 2, 1), COUNTA(A:A), 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have a list with thousands of sentences, so typing in the words in the formula does not work for me.

Is there a way to extract only the words in bold?

Comment: not really. you would need to play with scripts